# How do you give a UIButton a gradient and give that button a bottom shadow with that same gradient in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13

So my friend who's a designer made me a mock-up for a password generator I'm going to make https://i.stack.imgur.com/syour.jpg and I don't know how to code in that gradient using SwiftUI, the gradient of the button is #41A5ED -> #3099D8 and going in this direction (See picture) https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Fyh.jpg the top left is #41A5ED and the bottom right is #3099D8. I also want to give this button a bottom shadow like this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbBzG.jpg with the same gradient as the button. If you have any idea on how I would go around doing this please let me know because I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```swift
Button(action: createTask) {
                   Text(“MyButton“)
                       .color(.white)
                       .font(Font.system(size: 17))
                       .frame(height: 56)
                       .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                       .background(LinearGradient.actionButton, cornerRadius: 28)
                       .shadow() // configure shadow as you want
                   }
```

And just to improve code's readable I've created gradient separately:

```swift
fileprivate extension LinearGradient {
   static let actionButton = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(“ActionGradientFirst”), Color(“ActionGradientSecond”)]),
                                            startPoint: .topLeading,
                                            endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
}
```

Colors `ActionGradientFirst` and `ActionGradientSecond` I declared in **Assets.xcasset**

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but in case it helps someone else.

```
ZStack{
    LinearGradient(
        gradient: .init(colors: [Color.white, Color.blue.opacity(0.66)]),
        startPoint: .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0),
        endPoint: .init(x: 0.75, y: 0.75)
    )
    .mask(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
            .frame(width: 120, height: 45, alignment: .center)
            .blur(radius: 10)
    )
    .padding(.top, 20)
    Button(action: {}, label: {
        Text("Siguiente")
            .font(.custom("Avenir-Heavy", size: 20))
            .padding(.top, 10)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
            .padding(.leading, 16)
            .padding(.trailing, 16)
    })
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .background(
        LinearGradient(
            gradient: .init(colors: [Color.white, Color.blue.opacity(0.75)]),
            startPoint: .init(x: -0.33, y: -0.33),
            endPoint: .init(x: 0.66, y: 0.66)
        ))
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
}
.frame(height: 100)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

First create a gradient using the following method,

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
```

Then simply apply it to any view you want,

```
view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

To add a shadow,

```
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds)
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.grey.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0.5)
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    view.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
```

Comment: That's UIKit I'm talking about the new SwiftUI framework.